# How to check if a swf is loaded using JavaScript with swfobject?

Tags: javascript, swfobject

I have the following swf:

```
    <head>
    # load js
    <script>
    function graph() {
     swfobject.embedSWF(
     "open-flash-chart.swf", "chart", "400", "180", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf",
     {"data-file":"{% url monitor-graph %}"});
        };
    </script></head>

<div id="chart"> </div>
<script>
graph();
</script>
```

I would like to call the graph function only if the swf has not been loaded yet, is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

The last argument to `embedSWF` is a callback function that is invoked when the swf has been embedded. It takes in an event object with a couple of properties denoting success/failure, etc. More on this at the `swfobject` [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/api).

```
swfobject.embedSWF(
 "open-flash-chart.swf", "chart", "400", "180", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf",
 {"data-file":"{% url monitor-graph %}"}, {}, {}, 
   function(e) {
     if(e.success) graph();
   }
 );
```

Comment: down voted - it looks like this is not always true. Since yes, docs tells us that last param is load handler. But it won't return true if file not found. This is a quote from the link you've provided - NOTE: success is report as true if the minimum Flash player required is available and that the Flash plugin-in <object> DOM element for the SWF was created. SWFObject cannot detect if the swf file request has actually loaded or not.

Comment: This is a partial solution. pipwerks answer is the right onw.

Answer (score 11):

Use SWFObject to embed the SWF, then use the callback function to poll the SWF's `PercentLoaded` value.

If the value is 0, the SWF has not loaded yet. When it hits 100, the SWF is fully loaded.

Here's a [tutorial for polling `PercentLoaded`](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/executing-javascript-when-the-swf-has-finished-loading/), complete with code examples.

Comment: This is the correct and complete solution. Even if it is more than a year old, it should be marked as such.

Comment: Tried this but am getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined " error.

Comment: `e` is defined in the function like this `var callbackfn = function(e) { if(e.success){} }`.

Answer (score 0):

The swfobject callback only returns success if the  DOM element was successfully created. It doesn't actually say anything about whether or not the SWF has loaded.

From the swfobject documentation:

> NOTE: success is report as true if the minimum Flash player required is available and that the Flash plugin-in  DOM element for the SWF was created. SWFObject cannot detect if the swf file request has actually loaded or not.