# How to position flash over text

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

I have flash which can take some time to load. I want to inform the user that it is loading and they should just wait. What I'm thinking is I could just put text under the flash content and when the flash content loads the text will be hidden by the content. Here's what I have so far:

```
<object id="call-widget" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="https://clients4.google.com/voice/embed/webCallButton" width="230" height="85">
  <param name="movie" value="https://clients4.google.com/voice/embed/webCallButton" />
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
  <param name="FlashVars"  value="id=a8dd9c58da5043dca0e879988f5cadc447e74f7a&style=0" />
</object>
<span style="z-index:-1;">Google Voice is loading...</span>
```

This will place the text "Google Voice is loading..." **beside** the flash content instead of **behind** it. It works ok if I put `position:fixed` or `position:absolute` however I have this html in a [TINYBox2](http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/) and by setting the position as fixed it offsets the content out of the TINY box (looks unnatural). Is there any way I could put that `<span>` in the center of the TINYBox2 and be behind the flash content?

**Note:** I have no control over the flash (it's provided by Google Voice)

---

Here's what the TINYBox2 code is:

```
TINY.box.show({html: theHtmlYouSeeAbove});
```

What it should look like is:

[image: With text behind]

With text behind the flash content to be seen only when it's loading.

Comment: @popnoodles I disagree. It would be different if it weren't for the javascript of TINYBox2 or the html of the text, or the flash of the flash content...

Comment: The link to TINYBox2 is in the OP. I'll post what it does for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using TinyBox apply this to the tinner class

```
.tinner {
  position:relative;
}
```

Now you can have your span with a position absolute and give the top/left/right/bottom positions relative to the div its in (.tinner assuming the TinyBox).
Don't worry about the z-index as a flash file will certainly be on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can do the opposite. First load the Flash and over the flash put your loading text in a floating div. To do this just need to play a little with the css z-index property. Then when the flash is loaded, you can simply hide the div from inside the flash, by executing the some javascript function that does the hiding trick.

For the div on top, just do a div with the text/html you want and with the css

```
<div id="splash" style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;top:10px;width:100px;height:200px;" >the flash is loading...</div>
```

From inside the flash file, after loading (for instance on the fist frame), put some code like this...

```
getURL("javascript:myfunction();");
```

And place this js in your html...

```
<script language="javascript">
function myfunction() {
   $('splash').hide();
}
</script>
```

Thanks!,

@leo.
r

Comment: I don't have control over the flash file. It's provided to me by Google Voice.

Comment: well in that case I reccomend to change the way you load your flash, by using swfobject. This is a super easy to use api that allows you to load your movies and attach events after it is loaded. Check this example here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939630/how-to-check-if-a-swf-is-loaded-using-javascript-with-swfobject

Comment: In your case you will hide the floating div from inside the callback function from the swfobject.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work, but I'm pretty sure I was doing something wrong. I think it would work so upvote for that. Thanks!