# Removing delay or placing a listener to swfobject once its done loading

Tags: javascript, php, flash, swfobject

I am trying to embed an swf

Here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
       function initSwf(path) 
       {
         var playerso = new SWFObject(path.concat("/playerHD.swf"), "player01", "600", "450", "9");
     playerso.addParam("quality", "high");
     playerso.addParam("allowScriptAccess", "always");
     playerso.addVariable("xml", path.concat("/xml/details.xml")); // Data xml URL
     playerso.addVariable("path", path.concat("/files/")); // URL for assets (swf & jpg)

     playerso.write("dviewDiv");     
     jQuery(document).ready(function() 
     {
            setTimeout( function()
            { 
                jQuery('#mySliders').addClass('hide');
                                jQuery('#sliderloading').addClass('hide');
                                             jQuery('#dviewDiv').removeClass('hide');
            }
            , 7000 );              
     });
    }
</script>
```

The problem with this swfobject is, while it loads, it shows a blank screen or white or whatever background i provide. Which seems bad user experience

I want to modify the library so that while it buffers, i can show some other images and when its buffer is complete it disappears.

As in my code above i have placed a 7 second delay on removing images. It helps but still sometimes the loading takes more than 7 seconds. Is there any possiblity or any modification i can do to find out when it finishes loading so i can remove images then.

example can be viewed on

```
thevowapp.com/webapp/test.php

Press on 3D BUtton to load the swf file
```

The library code is as follow

The javascript opensource library i am using has following code

```
/**
 * SWFObject v1.4: Flash Player detection and embed - http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/
 *
 * SWFObject is (c) 2006 Geoff Stearns and is released under the MIT License:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 * **SWFObject is the SWF embed script formerly known as FlashObject. The name was changed for
 *   legal reasons.
 */
if (typeof deconcept == "undefined") {
    var deconcept = new Object();
}
if (typeof deconcept.util == "undefined") {
    deconcept.util = new Object();
}
if (typeof deconcept.SWFObjectUtil == "undefined") {
    deconcept.SWFObjectUtil = new Object();
}
deconcept.SWFObject = function (_1,id,w,h,_5,c,_7,_8,_9,_a,_b) {
    if(!document.createElement||!document.getElementById){
        return;
    }
    this.DETECT_KEY = _b?_b:"detectflash";
    this.skipDetect = deconcept.util.getRequestParameter(this.DETECT_KEY);
    this.params = new Object();
    this.variables = new Object();
    this.attributes = new Array();
    if (_1) {
        this.setAttribute("swf",_1);
    }
    if (id) {
        this.setAttribute("id",id);
        }
    if (w) {
        this.setAttribute("width",w);
    }
    if (h) {
        this.setAttribute("height",h);
    }
    if (_5) {
        this.setAttribute("version",new deconcept.PlayerVersion(_5.toString().split(".")));
    }
    this.installedVer=deconcept.SWFObjectUtil.getPlayerVersion(this.getAttribute("version"),_7);
    if (c) {
        this.addParam("bgcolor",c);
    }
    this.addParam("wMode","transparent");
    var q=_8?_8:"high";
    this.addParam("quality",q);
    this.setAttribute("useExpressInstall",_7);
    this.setAttribute("doExpressInstall",false);
    var _d=(_9)?_9:window.location;
    this.setAttribute("xiRedirectUrl",_d);
    this.setAttribute("redirectUrl","");
    if (_a) {
        this.setAttribute("redirectUrl",_a);
    }
};
deconcept.SWFObject.prototype = {
    setAttribute:function(_e,_f) {
        this.attributes[_e] = _f;
    },
    getAttribute:function(_10) {
        return this.attributes[_10];
    },
    addParam:function(_11,_12) {
        this.params[_11]=_12;
    },
    getParams:function() {
        return this.params;
    },
    addVariable:function(_13,_14) {
        this.variables[_13]=_14;
    },
    getVariable:function(_15) {
        return this.variables[_15];
    },
    getVariables:function() {
        return this.variables;
    },
    getVariablePairs:function() {
        var _16=new Array();
        var key;
        var _18=this.getVariables();
        for(key in _18){
            _16.push(key+"="+_18[key]);
        }
        return _16;
    },
    getSWFHTML:function() {
        var _19="";
        if (navigator.plugins&&navigator.mimeTypes&&navigator.mimeTypes.length) {
            if (this.getAttribute("doExpressInstall")) {
                this.addVariable("MMplayerType","PlugIn");
            }
            _19="<embed type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" src=\""+this.getAttribute("swf")+"\" width=\""+this.getAttribute("width")+"\" height=\""+this.getAttribute("height")+"\"";
            _19+=" id=\""+this.getAttribute("id")+"\" name=\""+this.getAttribute("id")+"\" ";
            var _1a=this.getParams();
            for (var key in _1a) {
                _19+=[key]+"=\""+_1a[key]+"\" ";
            }
            var _1c = this.getVariablePairs().join("&");
            if (_1c.length>0) {
                _19+="flashvars=\""+_1c+"\"";
            }
            _19+="/>";
        } else {
            if (this.getAttribute("doExpressInstall")) {
                this.addVariable("MMplayerType","ActiveX");
            }
            _19="<object id=\""+this.getAttribute("id")+"\" classid=\"clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000\" width=\""+this.getAttribute("width")+"\" height=\""+this.getAttribute("height")+"\">";
            _19+="<param name=\"movie\" value=\""+this.getAttribute("swf")+"\" />";
            var _1d=this.getParams();
            for (var key in _1d) {
                _19+="<param name=\""+key+"\" value=\""+_1d[key]+"\" />";
            }
            var _1f=this.getVariablePairs().join("&");
            if (_1f.length>0) {
                _19+="<param name=\"flashvars\" value=\""+_1f+"\" />";
            }
            _19+="</object>";
        }
        return _19;
    },
    write:function(_20) {
        if (this.getAttribute("useExpressInstall")) 
        {
            var _21=new deconcept.PlayerVersion([6,0,65]);
            if (this.installedVer.versionIsValid(_21)&&!this.installedVer.versionIsValid(this.getAttribute("version"))) 
            {
                this.setAttribute("doExpressInstall",true);
                this.addVariable("MMredirectURL",escape(this.getAttribute("xiRedirectUrl")));
                document.title=document.title.slice(0,47)+" - Flash Player Installation";
                this.addVariable("MMdoctitle",document.title);
            }
        }
        if (this.skipDetect || this.getAttribute("doExpressInstall") || this.installedVer.versionIsValid(this.getAttribute("version"))) 
        {
            var n=(typeof _20=="string")?document.getElementById(_20):_20;
            n.innerHTML=this.getSWFHTML();      
            return true;
        }
         else 
         {
            if(this.getAttribute("redirectUrl")!="") 
            {
                document.location.replace(this.getAttribute("redirectUrl"));
            }
        }



        return false;
    }
};
deconcept.SWFObjectUtil.getPlayerVersion = function (_23,_24) {
    var _25=new deconcept.PlayerVersion([0,0,0]);
    if (navigator.plugins&&navigator.mimeTypes.length) {
        var x=navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"];
        if (x&&x.description) {
            _25=new deconcept.PlayerVersion(x.description.replace(/([a-z]|[A-Z]|\s)+/,"").replace(/(\s+r|\s+b[0-9]+)/,".").split("."));
        }
    } else { 
        try{
            var axo=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
            for(var i=3;axo!=null;i++) {
                axo=new ActiveXObject("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash."+i);
                _25=new deconcept.PlayerVersion([i,0,0]);
            }
        } catch(e) {}
        if(_23&&_25.major>_23.major) {
            return _25;
        }
        if (!_23||((_23.minor!=0||_23.rev!=0)&&_25.major==_23.major)||_25.major!=6||_24) {
            try {
                _25=new deconcept.PlayerVersion(axo.GetVariable("$version").split(" ")[1].split(","));
            } catch(e) {}
        }
    }
    return _25;
};
deconcept.PlayerVersion = function(_29) {
    this.major=parseInt(_29[0])!= null?parseInt(_29[0]):0;
    this.minor=parseInt(_29[1])||0;
    this.rev=parseInt(_29[2])||0;
};
deconcept.PlayerVersion.prototype.versionIsValid=function(fv) {
    if(this.major<fv.major){return false;}
    if(this.major>fv.major){return true;}
    if(this.minor<fv.minor){return false;}
    if(this.minor>fv.minor){return true;}
    if(this.rev<fv.rev){return false;}
    return true;
};
deconcept.util = {
    getRequestParameter:function(_2b) {
        var q = document.location.search || document.location.hash;
        if (q) {
            var _2d = q.indexOf(_2b+"=");
            var _2e = (q.indexOf("&",_2d)>-1)?q.indexOf("&",_2d):q.length;
            if (q.length>1&&_2d>-1) {
                return q.substring(q.indexOf("=",_2d)+1,_2e);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
};
if (Array.prototype.push==null) {
    Array.prototype.push=function(_2f) {
        this[this.length]=_2f;
        return this.length;
    };
}
var getQueryParamValue=deconcept.util.getRequestParameter;
var FlashObject=deconcept.SWFObject; // for backwards compatibility
var SWFObject=deconcept.SWFObject;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939630/how-to-check-if-a-swf-is-loaded-using-javascript-with-swfobject)

Flash Player exposes a PercentLoaded property for the SWF, which you can poll while the SWF loads. Once it reports 100% you can manipulate your DOM (eg hide images) as you describe in your question. Be aware that you can't completely hide your SWF (mask or place off-screen), as this will prevent the SWF from loading in some browsers.

I wrote a tutorial for [polling PercentLoaded with SWFObject](http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/executing-javascript-when-the-swf-has-finished-loading/) a few years ago. It uses SWFObject 2.x, which is completely different syntax from 1.4. FWIW, SWFObject 1.4 is really old and is known to have bugs. I suggest using [SWFObject 2.3 beta](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject).

Comment: i am not very much expert in html and web coding. You can look at the code I am using to run swf. One swf is being made to run many swf. Check out the link i provided. Can you tell me, if i can covert same thing into 2.3? if its possible so i can try to do some effort

Comment: how do i do playerso.addVariable("xml", path.concat("/xml/details.xml")); // Data xml URL
     playerso.addVariable("path", path.concat("/files/")); // URL for assets (swf & jpg)
 in new SWFOjbect

Comment: in swfobject 2.x, you make them properties of the flashvars object: var flashvars = { path: path.concat("/files/") }